# Finding a linear function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let us consider $A: \mathcal{l}^2 \to \mathcal{l}^2$ given by the formula $$A(x_1,x_2, x_3,...)=(0,x_1, x_2,...)$$

Find linear function $B: \mathcal{l}^2 \to \mathcal{l}^2$ such that: $B \circ A= I$ and prove that there is no such function $C$ for which $A \circ C = I$ would happen. $I$ is identity.

I try to guess a proper matrix, but this hasn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's best to describe this in words (rather than trying to write down matrices). The operator $A$ shifts everything to the right. We need to choose a $B$ that reverses this. So what must $B$ do?

For the second part, note that $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is in $l^2$. Can $(1,0,0,\dots)$ possibly be in the image of $A$? And therefore, is it possible to choose a $C$ such that $A \circ C (1, 0 , 0 \dots) = I (1, 0 , 0 \dots)$?

Comment: $B(x_1, x_2, x_3, ...) = (x_2, x_3, ...)$?

Comment: Exactly! And what are your thought on the second part?

Comment: Thanks to your hints, now I see that it is impossible to obtain vector $(1,0,0...)$ because of the form of $A$. It is indeed quite more practical way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!